# Yeoman - Gruntfile.js generates source map at build but deletes it after any changes

Tags: sass, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, gruntfile

I installed Yeoman with angular generator, and it created Gruntfile.js. The problem is that after launching the webserver in the terminal with:

```
grunt serve
```

Yeoman generates main.css with in the end the reference of the source map

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

But after changing any scss the watch routine regenerates it without the reference of the source map in the end.

You can see my Gruntfile.js attached below:

```
    // Generated on 2015-06-16 using generator-angular 0.11.1
    'use strict';

    // # Globbing
    // for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
    // 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
    // use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
    // 'test/spec/**/*.js'

    module.exports = function (grunt) {

      // Load grunt tasks automatically
      require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

      // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
      require('time-grunt')(grunt);

      // Configurable paths for the application
      var appConfig = {
        app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
      };

      // Define the configuration for all the tasks
      grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        yeoman: appConfig,

        // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
        watch: {
          bower: {
            files: ['bower.json'],
            tasks: ['wiredep']
          },
          js: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
            options: {
              livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            }
          },
          jsTest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
          },
          sass: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['sass:server', 'autoprefixer']
          },
          gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
          },
          livereload: {
            options: {
              livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
              '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
              '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
              '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
          }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
          options: {
            port: 9000,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
            hostname: 'localhost',
            livereload: 35729
          },
          livereload: {
            options: {
              open: true,
              middleware: function (connect) {
                return [
                  connect.static('.tmp'),
                  connect().use(
                    '/bower_components',
                    connect.static('./bower_components')
                  ),
                  connect().use(
                    '/app/styles',
                    connect.static('./app/styles')
                  ),
                  connect.static(appConfig.app)
                ];
              }
            }
          },
          test: {
            options: {
              port: 9001,
              middleware: function (connect) {
                return [
                  connect.static('.tmp'),
                  connect.static('test'),
                  connect().use(
                    '/bower_components',
                    connect.static('./bower_components')
                  ),
                  connect.static(appConfig.app)
                ];
              }
            }
          },
          dist: {
            options: {
              open: true,
              base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }
          }
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
          options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
          },
          all: {
            src: [
              'Gruntfile.js',
              '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
          },
          test: {
            options: {
              jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
            },
            src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
          }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
          dist: {
            files: [{
              dot: true,
              src: [
                '.tmp',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
                '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
              ]
            }]
          },
          server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
          options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
          },
          server: {
            options: {
              map: true,
            },
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
              src: '{,*/}*.css',
              dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
          },
          dist: {
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
              src: '{,*/}*.css',
              dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
          }
        },

        // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
        wiredep: {
          app: {
            src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
            ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
          },
          test: {
            devDependencies: true,
            src: '<%= karma.unit.configFile %>',
            ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
            fileTypes:{
              js: {
                block: /(([\s\t]*)\/{2}\s*?bower:\s*?(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/{2}\s*endbower)/gi,
                  detect: {
                    js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
                  },
                  replace: {
                    js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
                  }
                }
              }
          },
          sass: {
            src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
          }
        },

        // Compiles Sass to CSS
        sass: {
          options: {
            includePaths: [
              'bower_components'
            ],
            sourceMap: true,
          },
          dist: {
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
              src: ['*.scss'],
              dest: '.tmp/styles',
              ext: '.css'
            }]
          },
          server: {
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
              src: ['*.scss'],
              dest: '.tmp/styles',
              ext: '.css'
            }]
          } 
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        filerev: {
          dist: {
            src: [
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
            ]
          }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
          html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
          options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            flow: {
              html: {
                steps: {
                  js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                  css: ['cssmin']
                },
                post: {}
              }
            }
          }
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
          html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
          css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
          options: {
            assetsDirs: [
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
              '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
            ]
          }
        },

        // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
        // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
        // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
        // to use the Usemin blocks.
        // cssmin: {
        //   dist: {
        //     files: {
        //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //       ]
        //     }
        //   }
        // },
        // uglify: {
        //   dist: {
        //     files: {
        //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
        //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
        //       ]
        //     }
        //   }
        // },
        // concat: {
        //   dist: {}
        // },

        imagemin: {
          dist: {
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
              src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
              dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
          }
        },

        svgmin: {
          dist: {
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
              src: '{,*/}*.svg',
              dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
          }
        },

        htmlmin: {
          dist: {
            options: {
              collapseWhitespace: true,
              conservativeCollapse: true,
              collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
              removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
              removeOptionalTags: true
            },
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
              src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
              dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
          }
        },

        // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
        // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
        ngAnnotate: {
          dist: {
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
              src: '*.js',
              dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
            }]
          }
        },

        // Replace Google CDN references
        cdnify: {
          dist: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
          }
        },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
          dist: {
            files: [{
              expand: true,
              dot: true,
              cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
              dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
              src: [
                '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                '.htaccess',
                '*.html',
                'views/{,*/}*.html',
                'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
              ]
            }, {
              expand: true,
              cwd: '.tmp/images',
              dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
              src: ['generated/*']
            }, {
              expand: true,
              cwd: '.',
              src: 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*',
              dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
          },
          styles: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
          }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
        concurrent: {
          server: [
            'sass:server',
            'copy:styles'
          ],
          test: [
            'copy:styles'
          ],
          dist: [
            'sass',
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin'
          ]
        },

        // Test settings
        karma: {
          unit: {
            configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
            singleRun: true
          }
        }
      });


      grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
          return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
          'clean:server',
          'wiredep',
          'concurrent:server',
          'autoprefixer:server',
          'connect:livereload',
          'watch'
        ]);
      });

      grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
      });

      grunt.registerTask('test', [
        'clean:server',
        'wiredep',
        'concurrent:test',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:test',
        'karma'
      ]);

      grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'wiredep',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concat',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'filerev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
      ]);

      grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build',
        'sass'
      ]);
    };
```

Comment: I didn't spot any errors in your file, but here was something that confused me at first: the default yeoman `grunt serve` doesn't actually generate a css in a styles folder. It creates a temp cashed css. "real" css gets built when you do a `$ grunt build`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with the watch task for sass

```
sass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass:server', 'autoprefixer']
      }
```

Change this to

```
sass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass:server', 'autoprefixer:server']
      }
```

Currently as the whole autoprefixer task runs on change of SASS file , both its subtasks also run , `autoprefixer:server` and `autoprefixer:dist`

The `autoprefixer:server` task updates and preserves the sourceMap whereas `autoprefixer:dist` task doesn't , which causes its reference to be removed from generated CSS file

Comment: Wow thank you! It is working and the explanation is clear! +1